# Capture logs for a duration

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'm trying to capture logs for a set period, parse it and produce a report. Here's what I do

```
(tail -F log_file | grep --line-buffered some_text | awk '{process lines} END {produce report}') & pid=$! && disown
sleep 60 
pkill -TERM -P $pid
kill -TERM $pid
```

Explanation:

1. `tail` a log file and pipe to `grep`, `awk` to process and produce report at `END`. Run these in a command group (within `()`)
2. Wait 60 seconds
3. kill the children of the process group (`tail`, `grep`, `awk`)
4. kill the command group

Now the problem is when `awk` is killed it won't write the report (complete the `END` part)! What am I doing wrong here? Can you suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already explained your problem.  "When Awk is killed, it won't write the report."

The proper solution is to only kill `tail` and then wait for the rest of the pipeline to finish.

If your `tail` supports the `--pid=` argument, that's easy -- just start a sentinel `sleep` process in the background, run for as long as you need to, kill the sentinel, wait for `tail` to exit.  Or use the `sleep 60` you are already using; just start it before the `tail` pipeline instead.

```
sleep 60 &
zzz=$!
tail -F log_file --pid=$zzz | awk '/some_text/ {process lines} END {produce report}'
wait $zzz
```

(Note also the refactoring to lose the useless `grep | awk`.)

If it doesn't, things easily get a lot more involved.  I can imagine that it might be possible by setting a clever `trap` in the subshell, but I would probably simply write a short Python or Perl wrapper with a signal handler to write the report when terminated.

Comment: `tail --pid` is the key here. Didn't know of that option